# Finding Total Energy for newton equation $\ddot x = -\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the total energy for the equation  $\ddot x = -\sin(x)$ using the fact that for $\ddot x = f(x)$ the total energy's defined as $$E(x)=-\int_0^xf(x)dx +\frac{1}{2} (\dot x)^2$$  And observe the solutions for this ODE when $t\to\infty$.
I did: $$\ddot x = -\sin(x) $$ 
$$\ddot x  \dot x = -\sin(x) \dot x$$ $$(\frac{1}{2}(\dot x)^2)'=(\cos(x))'$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(\dot x)^2=\cos(x)+c_1$$
So $E(x)=-\int_0^xf(x)dx +\frac{1}{2} (\dot x)^2= 1-\cos(x)+\cos(x)+c_2=c_3$
But How do I find it? or can't I?
Any hints/help?

Comment: From your definition isnt $E(x) = \cos x + \frac 12 (\dot x)^2$?

Comment: With the corrected sign it should be $E(x,v)=\frac12v^2+1-\cos x=\frac12v^2+2\sin^2(x/2)$ (constant term 1 to always have a non-negative energy).

Comment: What is $f$ here?

Comment: @CameronWilliams  edited. $f(x)=-\sin(x)$

Comment: Note that $$\int_0^x f(u)du=-\int_0^x \sin(\theta)d\theta=\left[\cos\theta\right]_0^x=\cos x-1,$$ and that you can't use $x$ as the variable of integration if it appears in a limit of integration. What does it mean for the total energy to be constant?

Comment: @bgins You're right of course but it doesn't changes the problem or getting me any further unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct. The only way to find the exact value of $E$ is if you know an initial condition (initial energy). The point is that the energy is conserved as you see since you get a constant value. This system (without units) models a pendulum acting under a uniform gravitational field. In such a system, energy is conserved since uniform gravity is a conservative force.

Comment: Good to see you back.  One point that should be emphasized is that the Total energy of a closed system is always conserved; there is nothing special here.  ;-))  - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Good point :)

Comment: The conservative nature of the force is not a requisite condition for energy conservation.  Mechanical energy can be converted to heat for example.